# [fuelphp]DBクラスとModelクラスのロールバック方法

Tags: php, fuelphp

現在Fuelphpを使用したアプリケーション内で、DBクラスとModelクラスで別々でトランザクションを貼ってテストを書いている部分があります。

・Modelクラス

```
<?php
class Model_Hoge extends Orm\Model {
    protected static $_table_name = 'hoge';
    protected static $_properties = array(
            'id',
            'name',
        );
    protected static $_connection = 'test_connection';
    public static function get_results()
    {
        // データベースに対する処理
        return 0;
    }
    public static function new_record()
    {
        Model_Hoge::forge(array(
            'id' => '5',
            'name' => 'ajapa-',
        ))->save();
    }
}
```

・テストクラス

```
<?php
use Fuel\Core\DB;
use Fuel\Core\TestCase;
use Fuel\Core\Format;
class Test_Model_Hoge extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        DB::start_transaction();
    }
    public function tearDown()
    {
        DB::rollback_transaction();
    }
    public static function initializeData($yaml_filepath)
    {
        $data = file_get_contents($yaml_filepath);
        $tables = Format::forge($data, 'yaml')->to_array();
        foreach (array_keys($tables) as $table_name) {
            $rows = $tables[$table_name];
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                try
                {
                    DB::insert($table_name)->set($row)->execute();
                }
                catch(Exception $e)
                {
                    DB::rollback_transaction();
                    throw $e;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public function test_hoge()
    {
        $this->initializeData(APPPATH . 'tmp/testdata.yml');
        Model_Hoge::new_record();
        $hoge = Model_Hoge::find('all');
        $this->assertEquals(1, count($hoge));
    }
}
```

この状態でテストを実行すると、ロールバック時にモデル経由で作成されたレコードが、DB上から削除されません。

原因としてはModel内の$_connectionで別途コネクションを貼っているからだと思っています。

こういった場合にテスト中に発生している全トランザクションを取り消すにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

DB::rollback_transaction(true);も試してみたのですが、Model側で発生したトランザクションまではロールバックされませんでした。

ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら、教えて頂けると非常に助かります。

Comment: Model側とテスト側で別々のコネクションを（ひょっとして別DB？）使わないといけないが、テスト完了時に両方ともロールバックしたい、ということでしょうか？

Comment: お察しいただき、ありがとうございます。まさしくその通りです。

Comment: それだとコネクションを指定して両方ともトランザクションを開始してロールバックするしかないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。コネクションを指定するといいますと、Modelクラスの$_connectionをDBクラスで使用する、というイメージでしょうか？

Comment: それでいいなら、すべて`test_connection`を指定すればシンプルでまた解決すると思います。しかし、「Model側とテスト側で別々のコネクションを（ひょっとして別DB？）使わないといけない」という前提なので、複数のコネクションがあるなら複数のトランザクションを処理する必要があると言いたかったわけです。

Comment: 仰るとおり、Modelクラスの$_connectionを使うことはできませんので、複数トランザクションを処理したいです。(本当はtest_connectionを使いまわせたらよかったのですが)。その場合、Model側のコネクションはどのようにロールバックすればいいかご存知でしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

モデルでのコネクションは`test_connection`ですが、テスト中のトランザクションはコネクションの指定がないため、たぶん`default`になります（正確にはdb.phpでの設定によりますが）。

ということで、トランザクションは`default`でしか開始されていません。

モデルでの処理をロールバックしたい場合は、`test_connection`でもトランザクションを開始してロールバックする必要があります。

`DB::start_transaction()`は引数にコネクションを指定できます。
http://fuelphp.jp/docs/1.8/classes/database/db.html#/method_start_transaction

Comment: ありがとうございます。`DB::start_transaction()`と`DB::start_transaction(Model_Hoge::connection())`でトランザクション別々貼ったところ、今度は`Model_Hoge::find('all');`を実行した際に、`DB::insert`で挿入した情報が読み込まれなくなりました。トランザクション分けると、別トランザクションで挿入したデータは読み込めなくなるものなのでしょうか？

Comment: @twintaro トランザクション途中のデータはロールバックされる可能性があるなど、不安定なものです。そこで多くの場合、コミットされるまでは他のトランザクションから見えないようになっています（この辺は「ACID特性」などで調べると出てきます）。[トランザクションレベル](http://gyouza-daisuki.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/11/19/150838)を指定することでコミットされていないデータを読むこともできますが、トランザクションを使うかどうか、コネクションを別にするかどうかについて再度検討したほうがいいかもしれません。

Comment: @unarist ありがとうございます。トランザクション分かれてるのを失念してました、見えなくて当たり前ですね。。

Comment: @kenjis 本回答で解決した場合には回答の承認をよろしくお願いします。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @kenjis 失礼しました。ご回答ありがとうございました！